# How do you create a deprecated Text in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-web

[image]

I want to create a deprecated text as shown next to the price of Rs.28499 . How do I do that?

Comment: You could try simply using a strikethough font:  ̶o̶l̶d̶P̶r̶i̶c̶e̶ ̶w̶a̶s̶ ̶$̶3̶3̶0̶0̶0̶

Comment: Text(
            "Deprecated",
            style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
          ),

Answer (score 2):

Try below code: refer [**`decorationThickness`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/decorationThickness.html)

```
Text(
      'Rs.234554',
      style: TextStyle(
        decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
      ),
    ),
```

Result-> [image]

Answer (score 1):

The property name that you're searching is the lineThrough.

You can update the style property of your `Text` widget and add the following:

```dart
TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Text(
  'Your text',
  style: TextStyle(
    decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
  ),
)
```